# Weblogic Error A RuntimeException was generated by the RMI server: weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am getting below error when I try to run my web app from Netbeans. This was working successfully but it stopped working after upgrading to MacOs Big Sur. Need your assisting to resolve this issue.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException. java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.security.SimpleCallbackHandler.(SimpleCallbackHandler.java:131)
at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate(RMIBootServiceImpl.java:114)
at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:645)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$2.run(BasicServerRef.java:534)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:386)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:531)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:138)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

A RuntimeException was generated by the RMI server: weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate(Lweblogic.security.acl.UserInfo;) java.lang.NullPointerException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.security.SimpleCallbackHandler.(SimpleCallbackHandler.java:131)
at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate(RMIBootServiceImpl.java:114)
at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:645)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$2.run(BasicServerRef.java:534)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:386)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:531)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:138)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Comment: did you found a solution? i have the same problem